# Can an Angular controller have multiple $resource?

Tags: angularjs, express, angular-resource

I have an angular controller that is instantiated with a $resource (e.g. /rest/book) and it is working fine.

I'm thinking of allowing the controller to work with another $resource (e.g. /rest/recommendedTitle) and i am not sure how.

This is how my controller currently looks like:

```
var dashboard = angular.module('dashboard', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute']);

dashboard.factory("Post", function($resource) {
    return $resource("/rest/book/:id");
});

dashboard.controller("DashboardCtrl", function($scope, Post) {
    // handle retriving a list
    Post.query(function(data) {
        $scope.books = data;
    });

    // user selected on a book
    $scope.bookSelectionListener = function(book) {
        $scope.selectedBook = book;

        console.log("Selected book id: " + $scope.selectedBook.bookId.S);

        console.log("Going to fetch similar titles which is in another table based on the book id");

         // call another $resource restful api to get recommended title
    };
});
```

Comment: Of course. Just create another factory.

Comment: Yes. But I'd name your factories better. One called "Books" and one called "RecommendedTitles" instead of "Post". They would then just pass in the api url to $resource in each factory as you have done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well just like you already did, have another factory creating a new `$resource` and inject it in your controller :

```
var dashboard = angular.module('dashboard', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute']);

dashboard.factory("Post", function($resource) {
    return $resource("/rest/book/:id");
});

dashboard.factory("Whatever", function($resource) {
    // you should probably initialize some particular method depending on your backend here
    return $resource("/rest/whatever/:id");
});

dashboard.controller("DashboardCtrl", function($scope, Post, Whatever) {
    // handle retrieving a list
    Post.query(function(data) {
        $scope.books = data;
    });

    // user selected on a book
    $scope.bookSelectionListener = function(book) {
        $scope.selectedBook = book;

        console.log("Selected book id: " + $scope.selectedBook.bookId.S);

        console.log("Going to fetch similar titles which is in another table based on the book id");

         // call another $resource restful api to get recommended title

         Whatever.query({bookId : book.id}, function(data) {
             $scope.similarBooks = data;
         });

    };
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Related resources can always be grouped together in factory.

```
dashboard.factory("Post", function($resource) {
    return {
           books:$resource("/rest/book/:id"),
           recommendedTitles:$resource("/rest/recommendedTitles")
    };
});
```

And then in controller, resource is available to be used:

```
Post.books.query()
Post.recommendedTitles.query()
```